# Windows 8 screen flashes

Tags: windows-8, display, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Windows 8 64 bit installation upgraded from a Windows 7 Ultimate installation, with an nVidia card and the latest signed drivers(306.97 as of this writing, a single bundle for both Windows 7 & 8). At random the screen flashes to black for a second upon mouse clicking.

Is this a known problem, and is there a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried the beta version of the drivers?

Comment: Nope..does it help fix this?

Comment: @Rex it vastly improves the situation

Comment: have u tried reinstalling? maybe something went wrong during installation. or try a refresh (if you don't mind) and then install all drivers again